# Best practice of SQL Server Index of datetimes

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

If I have a table that has an index

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, createDate
```

But also would like an index that goes

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, closeDate
```

Can I combine the two dates in one index, because I believe that datetimes must be the end of a index. Makes little point in organize after a single point of time, or am I wrong?

Nothing like this is possible right? Without using include.

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, (createDate, closeDate)
```

They are both used erratic, I guess it would still do a hash join, so it doesn't matter that is two separate indexes?

The query optimizer seem to pick the wrong plans so we are trying to force the optimizer using WITH (INDEX(index)) for the right plan. But it is hard to determine it.

Comment: How about the table definition including indexes? And maybe the query that is using a plan that you consider to be less than optimal? Otherwise you are asking to provide specifics on a generalized example.

Comment: What is the query that you are indexing for?

Comment: Can you have two dates in one index? Yes, of course you can!  Can I give you good advice about indexing without seeing a query (let alone DDL)?  No, of course I can't!

Comment: they're quite wide indexes, especially if you're making two of them! as MJH says if you include more details about the table and query you may get more meaningful responses; but I'd be very wary of having two indexes with four of five keys the same.